# set id to auto increment using Visual Studio 17 on a table created in server explorer

Tags: visual-studio

[image: What i want to auto increment]

When I right click Id and hit properties I see where I think I should be able to change it by setting identity increment to 1 and identity seed to 1 and is identity to true.

Only I can't seem to figure out how...
[image: Where do I change this?]
Any ideas by the pros?

Comment: Nope every properties page i ever seen has a right justified Arrow you can click to change.. This screen does not

Comment: Yes sir. It appears you have to load the actual table into the designer tool. Then you can right click the Id Row and hit properties. Then it will show you a different properties page that is able to be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you have to load the actual table into the designer tool. Then you can right click the Id row and hit properties. Then it will show you a different properties page that is able to be changed. Hit update when done making the changes.